# Airflow + sqlalchemy short-lived connections to metadata db

Tags: sqlalchemy, celery, airflow

I deployed the latest airflow on a centos 7.5 vm and updated `sql_alchemy_conn` and `result_backend` to postgres databases on a postgresql instance and designated my executor as `CeleryExecutor`. Without enabling any dag at all and even with no airflow scheduler started, I see about one connection established  every 5 seconds and then disposed to run a `SELECT 1` and a `SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1`.

The number of short-lived connections drastically increase when one starts the scheduler and turns on dags. Does anyone know the reason for this? Is this a heartbeat check or task status check? With `sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True` in airflow.cfg should these connections not be longer lived? Is there a log that I can look to pinpoint the source of these connections with sub-second life?

Config values used for reference

```
    executor = CeleryExecutor
    sql_alchemy_conn = postgres://..../db1
    sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True
    sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
    sql_alchemy_max_overflow = 0
    parallelism = 32
    dag_concurrency = 16
    max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
    worker_concurrency = 16
    broker_url = redis://...
    result_backend = db+postgresql+psycopg2://.../db2
    job_heartbeat_sec = 5
    scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5
```

Comment: Try adding `sql_alchemy_pool_size` with the appropriate number. If you don't specify the default is 5. So try increasing the number

Comment: thanks @kaxil the pool size was 5. increasing it seemed to help until i turned on a single dag and it immediately tripled my number of short-lived connections. And turning off the dag does not seem to turn of the processes that ping the database. I still see very high number of `select 1`s and `select cast('test plain returns' as ...`   Is there a setting that I am missing to ensure that these pings use connections from the sqlalchemy's connection pool? Also, could you point me to the log that I should be seeing this activity as I can't seem to locate anything in the airflow logs.

Comment: setting `logging_level = DEBUG` is providing a lot more information for me regarding what's happening with sqlalchemy via settings.py. Please disregard my log question

Comment: @chi did you ever come to find anything promising after setting up logging? Running into the same issue myself now with large number of connections despite having connection pooling enabled.

Comment: any follow-up on this??

Answer (score 1):

Set `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_POOL_PRE_PING` to `False`.

Check connection at the start of each connection pool checkout. Typically, this is a simple statement like `SELECT 1`.

More information here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-pessimistic

Comment: Have spent almost 8 hours, really saved me a lot!